# Parsing Complex JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I have the below JSON field in my data.

```scala
val myjsonString = """[{"A":[{"myName":"Sheldon""age":30"Qualification":"Btech"}]"B":"UnitedStates"},{"A":[{"myName":"Raj""age":35"Qualification":"BSC"}]"B":"UnitedKIngDom"},{"A":[{"myName":"Howard""age":40"Qualification":"MTECH"}]"B":"Australia"}] """
```

The parse method gives the following structure:

```scala
scala > val json = parse(myjsonString)
json: org.json4s.JValue = JArray(List(JObject(List((A,JArray(List(JObject(List((myName,JString(Sheldon)), (age,JInt(30)), (Qualification,JString(Btech))))))), (B,JString(UnitedStates)))), JObject(List((A,JArray(List(JObject(List((myName,JString(Raj)), (age,JInt(35)), (Qualification,JString(BSC))))))), (B,JString(UnitedKIngDom)))), JObject(List((A,JArray(List(JObject(List((myName,JString(Howard)), (age,JInt(40)), (Qualification,JString(MTECH))))))), (B,JString(Australia))))))
```

I am trying to parse it using Scala `json4s`. Visited almost all previously asked questions related to this, however, could not get proper solution to this. The O/P should be something like this:-

```scala
UnitedStates 30
UnitedKIngDom 35
Australia 40
```

or only the age in `30#35#45` format.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is invalid, there are missing commas between your object fields.

In order to get the output that you want you will need to extract the data from the parsed AST that Json4s will create upon successful parsing of the data. Json4s provides a number of ways with which you can manipulate and extract data from a parsed AST.

You could map over the list of objects inside the JArray and extract the country and age from each object. I don't wish to provide code to do this, as you haven't provided an example of what you have tried to do other than simply parsing the JSON string.

Comment: Hey Richard, Thanks for the update! I am new to Scala JSON parsing. After parsing the given json string (assuming commas between the object fields ), I want to get the age corresponding to each country -

Comment: The O/P should looks like :-UnitedStates 30
UnitedKIngDom 35
Australia 40
or only the age in 30#35#45 format.